# Delaunay triangulation of point cloud

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, delaunay

I want to triangulate a 3D point cloud using Delaunay algorithm. To test my code I extract the points clouds from an STL file and then try to remesh it. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

#--------------def funtion extract point cloud-------------------
def point_cloud(inp):
    node = []
    for line in inp:
        temp1 = line.strip()
        x = temp1.split()
        if x[0] == "vertex": 
            del x[0]
            node.append(x)
    node = set(map(tuple,node))
    return node
#--------------------end function---------------------------------

with open("D:\\cilinder.stl","r") as fo:
    pc = point_cloud(fo)

u = []
v = []
w = []

for l in pc:
    u.append(float(l[0]))
    v.append(float(l[1]))
    w.append(float(l[2])) 

ua = np.array(u)
va = np.array(v)

#tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)
tri = Delaunay(np.array([u,v]).T)

points = []
vertex = []

for i in range(ua.shape[0]):
    points.append([ua[i],va[i],w[i]])

for vert in tri.simplices:
#for vert in tri.triangles:
    vertex.append(vert)      

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(ua, va, w, triangles=tri.simplices, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
#ax.plot_trisurf(ua, va, w, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.show()
```

After I run this code I got the following result:

Results:

[image]
[image]

The algorithm does not triangulate the external surface of the point cloud. I can't figure out why I got this result. Any suggestion?

EDITED: I just figured out that the function point_cloud provides duplicated points, as they are directly extracted from the STL file.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a triangular surface mesh or a tetrahedral volume mesh?

Comment: a triangular surface mesh

Comment: Alright, the problem is clear then: Given just a point cloud, `Delaunay` has no way of knowing which connections are supposed to be the "outside" of the resulting shape. It just connects some, resulting in the funny-looking thing you got.

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get the meshes as you display them is that you did not (and cannot) provide topological information to scipy's Delaunay mesher. You give it a point cloud, it connects all the dots, that's it.

Mesh generation is a complex topic, and unfortunately I don't know of any software that, given a point cloud and topological information, gives you a mesh.

However, there are various ways of how to generate a mesh from scratch, just given the geometry of the object. For the cylinder you have in mind, one way is to do it by yourself; check out [meshzoo](https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo/blob/master/meshzoo/tube.py):

```py
import meshio
import numpy as np


def create_mesh(width=5.0, n=30, radius=1.0):
    # Number of nodes along the width of the strip (>= 2)
    # Choose it such that we have approximately square boxes.
    nw = int(round(width * n / (2 * np.pi * radius)))

    # Generate suitable ranges for parametrization
    u_range = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, num=n, endpoint=False)
    v_range = np.linspace(-0.5 * width, 0.5 * width, num=nw)

    # Create the vertices.
    nodes = []
    for u in u_range:
        x = radius * np.cos(u)
        y = radius * np.sin(u)
        for v in v_range:
            nodes.append(np.array([x, y, v]))

    # create the elements (cells)
    elems = []
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(nw - 1):
            elems.append([i * nw + j, (i + 1) * nw + j + 1, i * nw + j + 1])
            elems.append([i * nw + j, (i + 1) * nw + j, (i + 1) * nw + j + 1])
    # close the geometry
    for j in range(nw - 1):
        elems.append([(n - 1) * nw + j, j + 1, (n - 1) * nw + j + 1])
        elems.append([(n - 1) * nw + j, j, j + 1])

    return np.array(nodes), np.array(elems)


points, cells = create_mesh()
meshio.write_points_cells("tube.vtu", points, {"triangle": cells})
```

[image]

Making a zig-zag out of this should be easy, too.

Other mesh generators:

- [mshr](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/mshr)
- [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh)
- [gmsh](http://gmsh.info/)/[pygmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh)
- [MeshPy](https://github.com/inducer/meshpy)

Comment: the problem is that I have to do it starting from a point cloud.

Comment: Along with the point cloud, you also need geometry info; you'll otherwise get what you got. And if you have geometry, you don't need points. That's why there are no mesh generators of the kind you're looking for. For domains that are topologically equivalent to a flat surface, you could remap the points to a surface, do Delaunay there, and map back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got your point. But what if you have a point cloud coming from scanned geometry? You won't have any kind of information about the geometry.  My goal was to work on a point cloud coming from a scanning of a complex geometry.

Comment: That is, quite simply, not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a delaunay triangulation but with tetrahedons. Then remove holes manually. IMO its a tetrahedal volume mesh. Especially the Bowyer-Watson algorithm is easy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunatly I was lookign for a way to automatize the process, as the point clouds comes from a scanned geometry whse feature are known (e.g. concave) with a quite regular surface. I'll keep looking for a solution and I will update the discussion as soos as, and if, I will find it.